# name 'openpyxl' not defined error

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-imaging-library

Still learning the ins and outs of python here.  I've had minor success with using openpyxl library and started this pet project of using excel file as a "canvas" to read a 1 bit bmp file from directory then to "duplicate-display" the image on the worksheet by getting rid of the guides, decreasing the sizes of each cell and finally by adding a small image in each cell with list of binary data from getdata method from pillow.

I have not gone through the entire logic, but I am having trouble with below code for two nights and I still have no clue why I am getting name 'openpyxl' not defined error in the line almost at the bottom withe the code `sheet.add_image(openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('square_blue.jpg'), colnum_string(col)+str(row))`
I had success with similar project using almost identical importing of both openpyxl and PIL libraries.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
from PIL import Image
# for file in os.listdir():
#   if file.endswith('bmp'):
os.chdir('c:/users/Sam/Desktop/py')
img = Image.open('trump.bmp')

img_width, img_height = img.size
pix_val = list(img.getdata())

wb = Workbook()

def colnum_string(n):
    string = ""
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n - 1, 26)
        string = chr(65 + remainder) + string
    return string

r_height = 3
c_width = 3

sheet = wb.create_sheet("Mysheet")
for col in range(1, img_height):
    sheet.row_dimensions[img_height].height = r_height
    for row in range(1, img_width):
        sheet.column_dimensions[colnum_string(col)] = c_width

        sheet.add_image(openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('square_blue.jpg'), colnum_string(col)+str(row))

wb.save('out.xlsx')
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Please provide the full error message you're seeing. Also, look at the `openpyxl.utils` module for a converter between numeric and alphabetic columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only import ''Workbook'' sub-module from openpyxel. Try:

```
from openpyxel import Workbook, drawing  # also import drawing namespace
[...]
sheet.add_image(drawing.image.Image('square_blue.jpg'), colnum_string(col)+str(row))
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This did work just fine.  I still don't get why though.  In my previous project where I had to place an appropriate image onto a cell from a list of hundreds of item numbers, it worked just fine.  Now I have an app to read in a bitmap file image, place a small jpg image into every one of the cells that correspond to a 1 value from the image data, remove all the guidelines, and show an excel sheet canvas with the image correctly translated onto it.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Sam, This works since you import `drawing` namespace from openpyxel. Without doing it, your interpreter do not even know what is this `drawing` your are adressing. This is equivalent to : ``import openpyxl``, then ``sheet.add_image(openpyxl.drawing.image...)`` By the way, I'm happy if I helped. Maybe you could accept the answer?